# Do we have any academic adverbs that mean "as it can be inferred or deduced"?

Tags: synonyms, adverbs

I am in the middle of writing an academic document.

My question is, do we have any academic adverbs that mean **" as it can be inferred or deduced"**?

I want this adverb to use at the beginning of my sentence.

**Example context:**

- We need money to buy food. *[adverb or adverb phrase]*, money is also
  important to keep us alive.

I am not sure if I can use the words **inferentially** and **deductively** at the beginning of my sentence or not. Also, please kindly let me know if you have any other suggestions.

Comment: Your connection is a consequence. Consequently, it needs the word 'consequently' to introduce the second thought. *Reading between the lines* is one way to pick up a hint, but your logic works in the other direction .

Comment: Are these like tax deductions?

Comment: Connect the dots: *We need money to buy food. That means we need money to keep us alive.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use ***hence*** which implies a logical connection or deduction. See [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hence)

> because of a preceding fact or premise : THEREFORE.

The definition of [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/hence) says

> as an inference from this fact; for this reason; therefore:
>
> - e.g. The eggs were very fresh and hence satisfactory.

Synonyms like ***subsequently*** would perfectly work as well. (see [WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/subsequently.html#C0-2))

Answer (score 0):

Ergo is an option too but I like consequently.